# What is the design rule for aesthetic rounded corners?

Tags: shapes

When is a rounded corner just right, when is too round or too squary ?
There are a bunch of rules in design such as the golden rectangle, the thirds, etc, is there one for rounded corners ?

[image: comparison]

Comment: Isn't it almost entirely dependent on the rest of your design?

Comment: I agree, there is not set standard that I know of. It would solely be dependent on your design as Dominic said.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is a rule, or even a suggestion about the size of rounded corners. That is purely aesthetic.

There are two key things to consider though:

1. **Consistency**. Standardize the radius over a project. Avoid mixing and matching rounded corners of various sizes without a good reason.
2. **Concentricity**. By all means, make sure your corners stay concentric if applicable. Our eyes expect to see concentric corners. Scaled corners just look odd.

[image]

See the [How to compute the radii (radiuses) of corners for concentric rounded rects](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8919/how-to-compute-the-radii-radiuses-of-corners-for-concentric-rounded-rects) for a little more info.